# Sci-Fi show from the 80's - Does anyone remember what it was called?

Tags: science-fiction, identify-this-movie

I have been haunted by a Sci-Fi show from my past.  It ran in the early to mid 80's and involved a large spaceship and its crew.  I remember several things about the show vividly:

In the first episode, the captain (who I remember referring to to fact that he could perform marriages) got trapped in an airlock and blasted out into space by accident.  This left a rather young and experienced officer in command.  The Admiral (or perhaps some other rank) was contacted and told of the situation.  He made the decision that the mission should continue and kept in close contact with younger officer.  I remember that his face would appear on a large view screen every time they communicated

The ship had a computer that was voiced by a woman.  The computer would get quite emotional if 'she' though that her systems were going to get damaged.

The ship eventually encountered another ship/local which they decided to fire upon (much to the aggravation of the Admiral, who did not want to see the thing shot at or damaged.)  Upon boarding the local, they discover a man that had been infused with machines (it was my first cyborg ever.)  The man seemed to attack them, and the disabled him and took him back to their ship.  Upon reviving him, the told them a sad story about how he had been taken and transformed, seemingly against his will.  Eventually, he was deactivated and left on a table.

I vividly remember him reactivating himself by touching his machine arm to a machine plate on his face and then getting up and starting to reek havoc on the ship.  He almost damaged the computer (much to her horror) before the officers corned him.  At this point, I believe he apologized and permanently deactivated himself, which really upset the crew who felt sorry for him.

That is the last thing I remember.

Help me remember what this show was.  I want to finish it.

Comment: What country do you live in?  Any idea on the country of origin of the show?

Comment: I was living in Atlanta Georgia at the time.  The show was classic American SiFi (in the 1980s.)  It ran around the same time as "Captain Power and the Soldiers of the Future" and looked very similar to "Battlestar Galactica" but the uniforms and sets were far more plain. It was broadcast television too, not cable

Comment: So far you're 2 for 2 on wanting to watch nonexistent finishing episodes :-(

Comment: Yeah, story of my life.  Still, I have two more that need names put to faces. Better luck next time I hope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it was not a series, there was a two part pilot that ran on the Disney Channel in 1988, called "[Earth Star Voyager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Star_Voyager)".

Several things fit your description:

1. Captain blown out airlock, leaving a 21 year old command cadet in charge
2. Computer voiced by a woman (Priscilla)
3. Person abducted when young and turned into a cyborg
4. Cyborg does rampage and eventually deactivate himself

However, I wish you luck in finding a copy to watch, as Disney never released it. Wiki references bootleg copies, so that may be your only recourse.

Comment: That's the one! Sounds like there were only two 'episodes', and I have seen all there is to see.  Still, I'll go back and re-watch it if possible.  Thanks

Comment: ...pretty good description coming from an 8 year old's memory hu? :)

Comment: I've actually got this on DVDR.  ;o)

Comment: How?  Is is available somewhere?

Comment: @Hoytman - Probably a bootleg copy, as DVDR is a home burned DVD.

Comment: We probably should not encourage bootlegging, but when would it be scheduled to become public domain?

Comment: @Hoytman - Depends on how it was written. If it was a work for hire, then 95 years from publication. If not, then life of author + 70 years. That's one reason the Beatles just released a new bunch of material, it extended the copyright on bootleg items that were circulating.

Comment: Since it's Disney, it will likely never enter public domain...

Comment: @MeaningfulUsername - Unless they change the law, it will. Mickey Mouse will enter the public domain as far as copyright in 2023 (At least the earliest Steamboat Willie versions, anyway). However, the character is also trademarked, and can't be used without permission. Something like this probably wasn't big enough to be trademarked, so eventually it will enter public domain.

Answer (score 0):

[Earth Star Voyager](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095077/) is the name of the movie.  It was a Disney movie.  The ship touted the "Bowman Drive" created by a short little guy who talked to himself.  The 2nd in command was named "Beany."